# Is this assembly comparison even mathematically possible?

Tags: assembly

Trying to disassemble an assembly program, and I'm stumped on a certain comparison branch.

Essentially I have this:

```
mov $0x2, %ebx
lea 0xffffffe0(%ebp), %esi
mov %ebx, %eax
add 0xfffffff8(%esi, %ebx, 4), %eax
cmp %eax, 0xfffffffc(%esi, %ebx, 4)
je 8048d59
```

So initially ebx has the value 2.

Then %esi points 8 blocks (words, value of 32) below %ebp in the frame.  **This is an input value, I'll call it X**

Then %eax gets the value 2.

Then the add function performs: eax =  2 + [X + 8] - 8

So X + 2

Now the cmp line performs: [X + 8] - 4

So X + 4

Now hopefully my understanding of the syntax here is wrong, because last time I checked X+4 is never going to equal X +2

Comment: `lea 0xfffffffe0(%ebp), %esi` - that's a 9 digit hex number there - is that a typo?

Comment: yep, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-8` and the `-4` apply to the address, not the value. Switch your tool to intel syntax, it will be more readable:

```
mov    ebx,0x2
lea    esi,[ebp-0x20]
mov    eax,ebx
add    eax,DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4-0x8]
cmp    DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4-0x4],eax
je     0x8048d6d
```

So, it's checking whether `x[1]==x[0]+2`

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but after printing the value in register %eax after the add, there is no way it could have done that.

At the location pointed to by %esi, the value 86 is stored.  After the add, %eax contains 88.

However 2 words BELOW %esi, a hex value is stored that looks to be an address.  It is 0x0804b930, or -133,908,176

Comment: That would make the value in %eax be -133,908,174

Comment: Doesn't matter what's below `%esi` because `x[0]` is at `%esi` and `x[1]` is at `%esi+4`. You do realize that `2*4-8=0` and `2*4-4=+4`, right?

Comment: I thought 0xfffffffc(%esi...) meant add 0xfffffffc to %esi, which would be 4 below...

Comment: Yes but `ebx*4` is also added, with `ebx` being `2`. See the intel syntax disassembly in my answer.

Comment: Okay now I'm really confused....I have been thinking that the value outside the parentheses is an **address offset**, and the stuff inside the parentheses is a **value offset**

Comment: No, there is no way to specify value offset in x86. It's all about the address. I can only reiterate, look at the intel syntax disassembly, all the additions are inside the brackets.

Comment: Okay makes perfect sense now.  I appreciate the suggestion to switch to intel syntax as well, but as my class deals only in GAS I will opt to stay with this, at least for the duration of the class

Comment: GAS can do intel syntax too, but I assume you really meant the class uses at&t ... so, no switch for you :)